# How to log the JSON calls made to my IIS server by another of my IIS servers

Tags: json, debugging, iis, mitmproxy

I have two .Net apps running on IIS servers that talk to each other with API calls.

I have an error that indicates some garbage (or non-encoded) characters are in them and would like to prove that before talking to dev's and perhaps even fix it myself.

Our apps don't have very much in the way of in-built logging so was starting to use a MITM type proxy to see the JSON in the body on the HTTPS posts.

This is more complicated than I hoped as HSTS is blocking the proxy's root cert (so was thinking of installing mine), http is not an option as by default hsts is also ensuring https,

However, I think this is getting complex, so I am stopping, and going back to first principles.

So my question is, as I have full access to all the machines and certificates being used, is there a better way to capture and see the JSON that one IIS based .net app is sending to the other?

Comment: Tools like Wireshark can capture and decrypt HTTPS packets. Pleas use a search engine to learn more.

Comment: I have a tool that can do that, I referred to that it the question, to do it requires a lot of complexity as they are doing a hacking technique called mitm and the modern web is designed to stop that. My question is simply that's as I "own" everything in the chain, is there a simpler/better way. (I have extensively "googled" before asking and drawn a blank)

Comment: Modern web prefers encrypted transmission that helps on things like privacy, but it does not stop legit ways to decrypt HTTPS packets. MITM proxy or Wireshark are just a few of the examples, while you can imagine enterprises rely on such to prevent sensitive information from leaking out. So for your situation it is unnecessary to search for anything else. BTW, tool recommendation is also off topic on this site.